# Unable to delete Snapshot using boto3 using python3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, syntax, boto3

I using `boto3` on the python3 for delete the snapshop, Getting below  error while trying to remove it (This syntax was work in the python2+boto only):

```
Tracebak (most recent call last):
  File "./snapshotcleanup.py"m line 158, in <module>
    s.delete()
 AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'delete'
```

Code :

```
connection = myinternalclient (User, pass)  
// Custom function for connection, you may consider ec2 = boto3.client('ec2') 



res = connection.describe_snapshots(OwnersIds=[XX], Filters=[{'Name' : 'tag:Name', 'Value' : ["nonimp*"]'}])

for s in res['Snapshots']:
    for tag in s['Tags']:
      if 'nonprod' in tag.value():
         s.delete()
          print("[Deleted Snapshot]: %s" % s['SnapshotId'])
```

Is this syntax not in the boto3 ?

Comment: Can you show the actual code which produces the error?

Comment: @Marcin Code added, Can you check this

Comment: Can you share how you get `res` ?

Comment: @Marcin added res connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete the snapshot, you can use [delete_snapshot](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.delete_snapshot) method.

For example:

```
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

for s in res['Snapshots']:
    for tag in s['Tags']:
        if tag['Value'] == 'nonprod':
            ec2.delete_snapshot(SnapshotId=s['SnapshotId'])        
            print("[Deleted Snapshot]: %s" % s['SnapshotId'])
```

Please **double check** the code as mistakes are possible, as one can delete wrong snapshots by accident.

The above assumes that the tags have the form (`Key` is not checked in the code above):

```
{
    'Key': 'env',
    'Value': 'nonprod'
}
```

Comment: `ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')` Line needed ?,  why can't use `res` ?  `s['SnapshotId']` variable gives the snapshotid to be be deleted, So Can i pass ID like `res.delete_snapshot(SnapshotId=s['SnapshotId'])`

Comment: @Nullpointer HI. `res` is only a dictionary of values. Deleting values from it won't translate to deleting snapshots in AWS. You have to call AWS API for that. You can use `delete_snahoshot`  or alternatively, `delete` on [Snapshot object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#snapshot) which you also need to explicitly  create. Either-way, you can't use `s.delete()` because it does not call AWS API.

Comment: @Nullpointer you can reuse `connection` object. I think its same as my `ec2`, though its not exactly shown in your question.

Comment: before `res` line, used `connection = myinternalclient (User, pass)`, So here Is it possible like `connection.delete_snapshot(SnapshotId=s['SnapshotId'])` ? Here I trying avoid to use ` ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')`

Comment: @Nullpointer I see that `connection` is a custom object `myinternalclient (User, pass)`. Thus I  don't know if you can re-use or not. If not, have to create new client.
Similarrly, if your `describe_snapshots` is different from boto3's [describe_snapshots](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_snapshots), then its impossible to provide correct answer as only you know how  `myinternalclient` works.